# Oracle Sql performance very slow

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have created aquery that joins several tables in Oracle, but the execution time is very slow, around 1-2 minutes. Is there a method to make the query faster?

```
SELECT S.ID STAFF_ID,
        d.year_enrol,
        C.COUNSELLOR_ID,
        count(*) Num_Of_Stud
FROM aab_ASSIGNED_COUNSELLOR C,
     aab_STAFF S,
     v_aab_student d
WHERE C.COUNSELLOR_ID = S.COUNSELLOR_ID
  AND SYSDATE BETWEEN C.EFFECTIVE_DATE_FM AND C.EFFECTIVE_DATE_TO
  AND C.HOST_COUNSELLOR_IND = 'Y'
  AND c.student_num = d.student_num
  AND (d.prog_code, d.subcode) NOT IN (('11345',' '),
                                       ('22678',' '),
                                       ('93451', ' '),
                                       ('62378','OPT'))
GROUP BY S.ID,
         d.year_enrol,
         C.COUNSELLOR_ID;
```

Comment: What's the size of the data? What indexes are currently on the three tables in the query?

Comment: Can we know the data structures as well as the indexes?, also, try using left join instead of old style joins

Comment: If your naming convention is consistent, `v_aab_student` is a view.  Is that so?

Comment: Has your teacher taught you about [EXPLAIN PLAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601) yet?

Comment: We've got nothing here to indicate why 1-2 minutes is slow.

Comment: v_aab_student is a view.  All tables have primary key as index. I cannot use Explain plan because I do not have enought priviledge for the v_aab_student view.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do your job without explain plan.

Comment: `Create Index` for each fields on the `WHERE` not just the Primary Key unless you dont have privilege for that neither.

Answer (score -1):

You should create index for each variable involve in the `where` part. You could create simple index or a composite for with all the field.

`Create Index` for each fields on the `WHERE` not just the Primary Key

aab_ASSIGNED_COUNSELLOR

```
COUNSELLOR_ID 
EFFECTIVE_DATE_FM 
HOST_COUNSELLOR_IND 
student_num
```

aab_STAFF

```
COUNSELLOR_ID
```

v_aab_student

```
student_num
prog_code
subcode
```

Also you can use [Explain Plan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231) to see what is doing the query. Sometime even when you add the index the planner decide not use it. That depend on your data size.

**ADDED notes.**

USE `INNER JOIN` instead of `WHERE` syntaxis, *this wont improve performace just for better reading*

And you may try creating an implicit table instead of using `IN`. With `Left JOIN` and `T.prog_code IS NULL` do the trick.

```
SELECT     s.id staff_id, d.year_enrol, c.counsellor_id, Count(*) num_of_stud 
FROM       aab_assigned_counsellor C 
INNER JOIN aab_staff S, 
        ON c.counsellor_id = s.counsellor_id 
INNER JOIN v_aab_student D 
        ON c.student_num = d.student_num 
LEFT JOIN 
           ( 
               SELECT '11345' prog_code,  ' '     subcode 
               UNION 
               SELECT '22678' prog_code,  ' '     subcode 
               UNION 
               SELECT '93451' prog_code,  ' '     subcode 
               UNION  
               SELECT '62378' prog_code,  'OPT'   subcode 
           ) AS T
       ON  D.prog_code = T.prog_code 
      AND  D.subcode = T.subcode 
WHERE      C.host_counsellor_ind = 'Y' 
AND        T.prog_code IS NULL 
AND        sysdate BETWEEN C.effective_date_fm AND C.effective_date_to 
GROUP BY   S.id, D.year_enrol, C.counsellor_id;
```

Comment: Creating compound indexes to satisfy queries without going to the table can be a useful technique in certain  circumstances.  But it should not be the first thing we do.

Comment: @APC I didnt say was the first thing or main thing. First are the index. but the main would be the `Explain Plan`